# Lax-Milgram theorem on Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis

Lax-Milgram theorem states that

If $B(,)$ is a symmetric,strictly positive and bounded bilinear form on Hilbert space $V$, then for any continuous functional $l$, there exists $u\in V$ s.t.
$B(u,v)=l(v)$.

I am wondering if this result can be extended to the case of Banach space,i.e. $B$ is defined on a Banach space $V$. By the condition of strictly positive and boundededness, we know that the topology of the Banach space is the same as the topology defined by bilinear form $B$, then we can use Riesz reprensentation theorem to prove it.

Comment: [This one](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pja/1195516650)?

Comment: Surfing the web, I've bumped into [this 2011 talk by Hideo Kozono and Taku Yanagisawa](http://web.math.unifi.it/ItalyJapan2011/Talks/kozono.pdf). The short answer seems to be: "More hypothesis are needed". Of course, the natural choice of setting would be the use of *two* distinct Banach spaces because ideally the pairing is a bilinear map $E\times E^*\to \Bbb F$, and Riesz does *not* yield an isomorphism $E\cong E^*$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would not be wrong, but useless.

If a strictly positive bilinear form exists on a Banach space $(V,\|\cdot\|_1)$,
then the Banach space is equivalent to a Hilbert space
in the sense that they have the same topology.

*Proof*:
As you already said, the topology defined by $B$ is the same as the original topology.
If $B$ is symmetric, you can show, that $B$ defines a scalar product on $V$, thus $V$ is a Hilbert space.
If $B$ is not symmetric, then $\langle x,y\rangle := B(x,y)+B(y,x)$ defines a scalar product.

So you cannot apply a Banach space version of Lax-Milgram to spaces such as $L^p(\Omega)$
for $p\neq 2$, because you cannot find a $B$ that satisfies the conditions.

Comment: I think technically $B$ is still missing the symmetry required of a scalar product, however using something like $\langle x,y \rangle = B(x,y) + B(y,x)$ should work.

Comment: I am thinking if the original norm satisfies Parallelogram law

Comment: @89085731 If the original norm satisfies a Parallelogram law, then it is a Hilbert space (if its that what you mean).

Comment: Maybe a silly question.Why $L^p,p\neq 2$ can not be homeomorphic to a Hilbert space

Comment: that is a good question and i think it is not so easy to answer.
Also for a finite measure space, the $L^p$ spaces are all equivalent, so you need extra conditions for the measure space.
Maybe it is worth to ask another MSE question why $L^p$ and $L^q$ are not homeomorphic if $p\neq q$, if there isnt such a question already

Comment: The reason I ask this question is because u say we can not define bilinear form on $L^p,p\neq 2$, so I think it is equivalent to the question I raise.

Comment: that was just an example, so i did not add any proof why $L^p$ is not homeomorphic to a hilbert space. If you want easier examples, consider $L^1$ or $L^\infty$ which are not reflexive, therefore not topologically equivalent to a hilbert space.

Comment: sorry what I mean is that why we couldn't have such bilinear form on $L^p,p\neq 2$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64038/discussion-between-supinf-and-89085731).